# iPhone 6 Plusの実機だけcrashする原因は？

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone

Swiftでアプリを作成し、iTunesConnectにsubmitしました。

1時間もせず、rejectの返事が返ってきたのですが（初めてのrejectでした）、
iPhone 6 Plus running iOS8.1
でcrashするためrejectする、とのメッセージでした。

添付されたcrash logを解析すると、
最初のViewControllerでviewWillAppearメソッドのところでクラッシュしていることが
判明しました。

それで、ここからが問題なのですが、
私自身はiPhone 6 Plusの実機を持っておらず、所持しているのは
iPhone 6, iPhone 5, iPad mini 2で、これらの３つのデバイスでは、
そのクラッシュが全く再現できないことです。

なお、metalを使っており、そのままシミュレーターでのテストはできないのですが、
metalの実装を削除したものでは、iPhone 6 Plusシミュレーターで、crashは
再現されませんでした。

iTunesConnectからのメッセージの中には、
release buildでのテスト方法、
テストしているbuildがsubmitしているものと同じかどうか確認する方法
が記載されており、それらの確認も行いましたが、
release buildでも再現できず、そのrelease buildはsubmit buildと
同じものであることも確認できました。

このような状況下で、再現できないcrashにどのように対処するべきか
悩んでおります。状況が、かなり限定的であり、なかなか同じ境遇という
ものはないかと思うのですが、もし、同じような経験談や、解決方法の
糸口でもいただければと思い、質問する次第です。

など、このアプリでは、
AVFoundation.framework（カメラ）
CoreMotion.framework（モーション）
Metal.framework（Metal）
などのフレームワークを使っています。
追加情報が必要であれば、適宜対応いたします。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

iTunesConnectの問題解決センターで返事が返ってきました。

Upon continuing with the review, we were unable to reproduce the crashing issue.

つまり元のbuildで問題なかったようです。なぜ、iPhone 6 Plusで問題が発生した
かのようになったのかは、結局不明です。
ちなみに、この後にとってつけたような、別の問題が提起されていました。
対象buildはバージョンアップで、指摘された別の問題に関しては、全く変更しておりませんし、
以前のバージョンで、問題視されたこともありません。
なお、この別の問題についても、一言説明を加えたら、そのままreviewが通りました。

Submitから１時間程度でrejectされたことから、Appleでの自動チェックシステムに
引っかかったのだと思っておりますが、必ずしも自動チェックのrejectは正しくない
ということを知ることができた良き経験だったと、今は思っています。